# Jersey hello world displays nothing

Tags: java, rest, maven, intellij-idea, jersey

I am new in rest web service with jersey, (with `tomcat`)

I have a `HelloWorld` source: (in the `RestApp` package)

```
package com.ss.hh;
...

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage(){
        return "Hello jersey";
    }
}
```

And here is the `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ss.hh</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Why i can't get the `Hello jersey` message in `http://localhost:8080/hello`?

**UPDATE**

I replace the `jersey-servlet` with `jersey-container-servlet-core` file and changed the `web.xml` configures as below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ss.hh</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But it not displays anything on: http://localhost:8080/FirstRestApp/hello

`FirstRestApp` is the project name.

Comment: Your `jersey-servlet` and `jersey-server` JARs are not the same version. Try using the `jersey-servlet` belonging to the `glassfish` groupId. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/

Comment: Also, if you want to use the URL as mentioned (`http://localhost:8080/hello`), the WAR deployed to the Tomcat server should be in the ROOT context. For that to happen, you need to clear your Tomcat's webapp folder (including the ROOT), and deploy your WAR file with the name `ROOT`.

Comment: @Rakesh I replace the jar file with the `jersey-server` , and change the `web.xml` content to `updated section` and not displayed anything.

Comment: Well, I tried deploying a simple Jersey webapp and noticed that there were 5 different dependencies that were required. `jersey-server`, `jersey-client`,`jersey-common`,`jersey-container-servlet-core` and `javax.ws.rs-api`. You could try with these and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IDE is `IntelliJ IDEA` the URL should be like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

(Without the project name)

Comment: nice guess with IDE, by the way did you thought by that angle?

Comment: Strange way to think about that problem - liked it.

Answer (score 1):

Add root context path in your url :

try `http://localhost:8080/FirstRestApp/hello`

Update :

I created small project exactly as you want with some modification and it is working fine for me..

https://github.com/darsh9292/FirstRestApp

Comment: I get `404 not found` error this time, on `http://localhost:8080/FirstRestApp/hello`